# Postcholecystectomy indigestion problem

Tags: liver

A pateint of lap cholecystectomy cannot now digest food rich in proteins and fats gets nausea and discomfort over hypochondrium after meals. So Is indigestion common after cholecystectomy?

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. This question is a bit unclear. It's kinda hard to decipher what you're asking. It looks to me like you're asking why the patient you mention is having indigestion problems, which may be a personal medical question and off-topic here. If this is what you're asking, you may want to edit to ask if indigestion problems are a known side-effect of laparoscopic cholecystectomies.